# Compilation on linux with defined target

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, makefile

I want to compile a project with a Makefile.

I have defined target for linux in one of my .h

```
#define LINUX_TARGET (COMPILER_GCC_4_4_1|FAMILY_LINUX|TYPE_X86)
...
#ifdef _LINUX_TARGET_
     #define __linux__
     #define TARGET LINUX_TARGET
...
#ifdef __linux__
#define __LINUX__
#endif
```

So in my Makefile I say that, I will use this target:

```
...
CFLAGS += -D_LINUX_TARGET_
...
```

Butwhen I compile i get this error :

```
 ../../../../../../../Generic/Common/Include/target_definition.h:145:0: warning: "__linux__" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define __linux__
^
../../../RefFT/Float/src/LIMITOR_main_32f.c:1:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
^
```

I don't understand why, beceause this works for macos or windows target...

**EDIT**

After Joachim Pileborg answer, what I did :

```
#define LINUX_TARGET (COMPILER_GCC_4_4_1|FAMILY_LINUX|TYPE_X86)
...
#ifdef _LINUX_TARGET_
    #ifndef __linux__
         #define __linux__
    #endif
    #define TARGET LINUX_TARGET
...
#ifdef __linux__
#define __LINUX__
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `__linux__` is *pre-defined* when building on Linux.

Comment: so I don't have to define it ?

Comment: Correct.  If you wanted to check to see if its defined and define it if its not, you can use #ifndef __linux__ first.

Comment: But If I don't define it in my Makefile I get this error `#error You have to define a target in your compiler project properties.` if it's not this, what could it be ?